# Changing Labels into Column Names in sas

Tags: sas

I have been googling around how to change column/variable label to Column/variable name in SAS.

so for example,

Right now,I have Column/variable name like this.

[image]

THEN column/variable label is like this.

[image]

I want to change to this label to column name

so i found this solution, but I am doing something wrong.

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Changing-Labels-into-Column-Names/td-p/520503

my data set name is work.Inst_char8

I tried like this.

```
  proc sql noprint;
    select cats(name,'=', case when label is not null then nliteral(label ) 
                                else name end) into: rename separated by ' '
    from work.Inst_char8
    where libname='WORK' and memname='Inst_char8';
    quit;


data Inst_char8;
set Inst_char8(rename=(&rename));
run;
```

The error is

The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: label, libname, memname, name

I know "Rename" works but I have 100 variables.

if there is a way, I can switch column label to column name except renaming each 100 variables.

I would love to know.

Thanks

```
Column Name

INSTNM
IALIAS
ADDR
CITY
STABBR

label

Institution (entity) name
Institution name alias
Street address or post office box
City location of institution
State abbreviation
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? You switched the FROM data set, you needed to leave it to query the sashelp.vcolumn data set not your own data set. Your data set name goes into the MEMNAME argument but you need to make sure the case is correct. That'll get you closer at least, I have not checked all your code.

Comment: @Reeza Sorry, I added it rest of my code. Proc sql part is already causing error, please let me know if you knwo the solution.

Comment: My initial response does give you the answer. You're querying from the wrong table, `FROM inst_char8` - change it to what was in the original query. The link doesn't work for me. Please take the time to look at the answer and what the table contains so you understand what the query is doing.

Comment: Please post example names and labels as text.  It is impossible to copy text from pictures and your pictures are too small to read.  Are your labels actually valid variable names? Only letters, digits and underscores and don't start with a digit.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for responses. I added the variable name and label.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It will probably make the dataset much harder to work with.

Comment: @supercooldjkazu I'll ask Tom's question again.  Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @Tom This is final dataset. I will send to Tableau. so users can understand meaning.  if you know, if  there is better way, please let me know. I am new to sas. Thank you so much.

Comment: I would raise the issue with Tableau why they are not giving you the option to use the labels in your Tableau workbook.

Comment: @Tom Thank you so much for helping me. I will check with Tableau!!!

Comment: Are you sending the data to tableau or an export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the labels are unique and valid to use as names then your basic method will work.  Note that names are limited to 32 bytes and labels can be up to 256 bytes long. And to use the labels in your example as names you need to set the VALIDVARNAME option to ANY.

```
options validvarname=any;
```

But you need to query the actual metadata table that has the variable attributes, not the data table.  Note that the LIBNAME and MEMNAME values in DICTIONARY.COLUMN are always uppercase. Also you cannot rename a variable to the name it already has.

```
proc sql noprint;
%let rename=;
select catx('=',nliteral(name),nliteral(substr(coalesce(label,name),1,32)))
  into :rename separated by ' '
from dictionary.columns 
where libname='WORK' and memname='INST_CHAR8'
  and name ne substr(coalesce(label,name),1,32)
;
%let num=&sqlobs ;
quit;
```

It is faster to just change the names using PROC DATASETS instead of copying the data. But if the list of renames is empty then you will get an error.

```
%if (&num) %then %do;
proc datasets lib=WORK nolist;
modify INST_CHAR8;
  rename &rename;
run;
quit;
%end;
```

If you are going to use the RENAME= dataset option then an empty list is fine.

```
data new;
  set INST_CHAR8(rename=(&rename));
run;
```

**If the ultimate goal is to load into Tableau then you might want to just write out a CSV file.** A CSV file does not have any place to store information on the data types, but Tableau in general ignores the actual data types of the fields and tries to classify the fields based on the values it sees.

```
proc export data=inst_char8 file='inst_char8.csv' replace dbms=csv label;
run;
```